# Intersection points convex hull and grid

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, integer-lattices, discrete-geometry, convex-hulls

I am trying to find the intersection points of the boundary of a convex hull of a finite set $S$ and a grid in multiple dimensions. How can I do this?

Comment: I want the exact locations of the points.

Comment: Even then haha... Buth then I would just take a coarser grid!

Comment: Thanks for your response! But that does not give me the intersection points with the boundary of the convex hull I think? Also the points inside the convex hull.

Comment: Indeed. I forgot you wanted the points on the boundary. You can perhaps use something like facet enumeration.